# Can i use python os.nice to lower the niceness of a celery task?

Tags: python, django, task, django-celery

Can i use python os.nice to lower the niceness of a celery task?

I was thinking of something like this:

```
@task()
def maintenance_requests():
    os.nice(5)
    request = requests.session()
    request.get('http://maintenance/', params={})
```

Is there any other way of doing this?

Thanks in advance!

EDIT: Since my application is IO bound, i've discovered that ionice was the command i needed. Did some tests, and it works like a charm. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think you can specify the niceness of a particular Celery task as niceness is a property of the process. A task is simply some code that runs on a Celery worker.

However you can setup a Celery worker with a lower niceness and route maintanance tasks to that worker using Celery's [task routing configuration](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/routing.html).

Comment: You can run `nice -n 5 ...` where `...` is your celery command.

Comment: Ok. Thanks. Will do some more research on the subject.

Comment: Well, i used nice to run the worker. After some testing, my benchmarks returned similar values for different values of nice. Maybe it's because my worker its IO bound.....

Comment: @luistm, if your worker is IO bound maybe try using `ionice` instead of `nice`.

Comment: @tjanes: That's what i said in the EDIT :). Thanks anyway!